# Problems with hideSoftInputFromWindow

Tags: java, android, flags

I'm new to java and android. I'm trying to close the keyboard after i press the button. I've read many topics of stacksoverflow and i know that i should use some method like this: `InputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(IBinder windowToken, int flags)`

I don't understand with this method. Topics i read in stackoverflow just gives the code. Can anyone explain to me what are the windowToken and flags for? I can't find the explanation in Google developers references.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

windowsToken is the token of the windows making the request. Can be returned by `View.getWindowToken()`.
flags is used if you want to provide addtional actions (see constant here : [developper doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY))